# If a post is marked as a duplicate, what happens if the original is deleted

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Example

[Internet usage monitor software](https://superuser.com/questions/346063/internet-usage-monitor-software)

This question is marked as a dupe, but the dupe cited has been deleted.

Should this be possible? Is it a bug or by design?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is by design. A question can always be deleted regardless of whether there are others who link to it as a duplicate.

Historically, linking as a duplicate was achieved by merely adding a link to a question's body. Now this is a bit different, so there could, in theory, be mechanisms that prevent you from deleting a question that is still linked to (or at least give you a warning).

Comment: Understood. Thank you

Comment: The problem is that once it's closed as a duplicate, no new answers can be added.  Closure is supposed to direct answers to the "master" question.  When the "master" is deleted, this question is still locked.  Seems like a flaw in the design.  In this particular case, the question is also off-topic, but that's not necessarily the case with all such questions.